# Formas de ejemplificar conceptos en un un texto

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras, vocabulario, vocabulario-técnico, rae

Tengo que escribir un texto breve con diferentes conceptos que tengo que ejemplificar. No quiero ser tan redundante colocando siempre "Por ejemplo" en cada ocasión.
Quisiera saber formas o estrategias para evitar esto para que el texto quede mas suelto y no tan repetitivo.

Answer (score 2):

- Esto incluye
- Entre ellos
- Particularmente/En particular
- Concretamente/En concreto
- Tal(es) como
- Especialmente/En especial
- Entre los cuales
- Específicamente/En específico
- Algunos ejemplos/ejemplares son
- Tanto X como Y son
- Para ejemplificar
- Ejemplificando
- Como los/las siguientes
- Considera los/las siguientes

Answer (score 0):

Aparte de los indicados por [Nameless](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/39697/formas-de-ejemplificar-conceptos-en-un-un-texto/39703#39703) puede utilizar:
[***verbi gratia***](https://dle.rae.es/verbi%20gratia?):

> 1. loc. adv. por ejemplo.

o

[**verbigracia**](https://dle.rae.es/verbigracia):

> 1. m. ejemplo (‖ hecho o texto que se cita para autorizar un aserto).
> 2. adv. por ejemplo.

o [**otrosí**](https://dle.rae.es/otros%C3%AD?):

> 1. adv. además. U. m. en leng. jurídico.